# Magento 2.2 Grid in custom module missing styles and format

Tags: module, magento2.2, grid, styles

We've successfully created a **custom module**, but it appears that none of the **js or css/less** is being applied to a **grid component** that is being used.

Any suggestions would be appreciated-

[image]

Comment: Have you run necessary command like?
Remove `var & generated` folder and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` And `php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: Already tried clearing everything and running every command we could find.  Its like assets are just not loading.

Comment: After further digging, it's not a css issue.  Its either a timing issue when loading all the stuff magento requires or a js issue.  Or both.